# how to make MKAnnotationView has A Number Or Title?

Tags: xcode, mkannotation, iphone-4, mkannotationview

I have an annotationView but I want to give a number At That annotationView

example:

I Have 20 annotationView at MKmapview, I want to Give a number for each annotationView, so the user who will use My application can see the number, so he know where is His target annotationView, because there is a number at each annotationView that have been declared before MKmapView Showing

HOw can I do That?

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the MKAnnotationView -- one of the simplest ways to do this is to set the image property on it.

If you only have up to 20 numbers, you might consider generating 20 images for each, storing them in the app, and just setting the image property on the annotation view.

Further -- you can customize MKAnnotationView by implementing drawRect, where you draw the requested number into your view.

Answer (score 0):

For people coming to this answer much later than when it was asked.
The `MKMarkerAnnotationView` has a `glyphText` property which can be easily set to a number.

If `MKMarkerAnnotationView` won't do, then I would suggest subclassing `MKAnnotationView` and working with it like you would a custom view. Note: `MKAnnotationView` has a `prepareForDisplay()` function often used for configuration. Apple have a sample project [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/decluttering_a_map_with_mapkit_annotation_clustering) which covers some good practices around building map UI.